# simple linear map problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $f$ be linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
If $f (x) = 0$ whenever $g(x) = 0$, is $f (x)$ equal to some scalar times $g(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $f(x) = 0$ whenever $g(x) = 0$ means that $f$ factors through the quotient $V/\ker g$, which is to say that there is a map $\tilde{f}:V/\ker g\to \mathbb{R}$ so that $f = \tilde{f}\circ\pi$, where $\pi : V\to V/\ker g$ is the natural map. But of course there is also an *isomorphism* $\tilde{g}:V/\ker g\to g(V)$ so that $g = \tilde{g}\circ\pi$. There are two cases:

- If $g(V)=\mathbb{R}$, then $V/\ker g$ is one-dimensional (since $\tilde{g}$ is an isomorphism), so the space of maps $V/\ker g\to \mathbb{R}$ is one-dimensional, and $\tilde{g}$ is a nonzero element of this space, so $\tilde{f}$ (which is also a member of this space) is a scalar multiple of $\tilde{g}$, so $f$ is a scalar multiple of $g$.
- If $g(V)=\{0\}$, then $g$ is the zero map, so clearly $f$ is also the zero map.